# Bootstrap 3 - What does "responsive" refer to?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm learning Bootstrap 3 and I see a lot of references to bootstrap being responsive or having responsive characteristics. Can someone explain what exactly *responsive* refers to? I think it refers to a bootstrap app being able to dynamically respond to different browser viewport sizes and having page content look good on mobile devices up to desktop. But, this is a guess on my part.

Comment: Change your browser size and look at how http://bostonglobe.com/ behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right; responsiveness refers to how well a website or app can adjust to being viewed at different screen sizes and different resolutions.

You can see this most dramatically in websites with mobile versions, like Facebook, which uses a different UI on phones and tablets, optimized for the smaller screen size.